# Why does registering another return value on an NSubstitute mock with a different value for an argument matcher throw a NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I've got a .NET Core Xunit project targeting .NET 4.6 which is using NSubstitute 3.1.0.  I'm setting up a mocked object which needs to return different things based on different arguments received.  Here's some sample code (and a [link to the github repo](https://github.com/greyseal96/NSubstitute_SOQuestion.git) for the source code of the full project):

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    private IFoo getMockFoo()
    {
        int instanceIDPool = 1;
        IFoo foo = Substitute.For<IFoo>();
        foo.AddBar(Arg.Is<BarInfoObj>(x => x.ServerName.Contains("SuccessAddNewBar"))).Returns(ci =>
        {
            BarInfoObj barInfoObjToReturn = ci.ArgAt<BarInfoObj>(0).ShallowCopy();
            barInfoObjToReturn.BarInstanceId = instanceIDPool++;
            barInfoObjToReturn.Status = BarStatus.Idle;
            barInfoObjToReturn.StatusMessage = "Newly registered Bar";
            barInfoObjToReturn.StatusReportDateTimeUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now);
            string msg = $"Added Bar at {barInfoObjToReturn.BarUrl} with instance ID {barInfoObjToReturn.BarInstanceId.ToString()} to the Foo's pool of Bars.";
            return Response<BarInfoObj>.Success(barInfoObjToReturn, msg);
        });
        //This second return value registration throws a NullReferenceException.
        //This won't throw an exception if I comment out the return registration above; the
        //exception is thrown whenever there is more than one return value registration.
        foo.AddBar(Arg.Is<BarInfoObj>(x => x.ServerName.Contains("SuccessAddExistingBar"))).Returns(ci =>
        {
            BarInfoObj barInfoObjToReturn = ci.ArgAt<BarInfoObj>(0).ShallowCopy();
            barInfoObjToReturn.BarInstanceId = instanceIDPool++;
            barInfoObjToReturn.Status = BarStatus.Idle;
            barInfoObjToReturn.StatusMessage = "Re-registered Bar";
            barInfoObjToReturn.StatusReportDateTimeUTC = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime.Now);
            string msg = $"Re-registered Bar at {barInfoObjToReturn.BarUrl} with instance ID {barInfoObjToReturn.BarInstanceId.ToString()}.";
            return Response<BarInfoObj>.Success(barInfoObjToReturn, msg);
        });

        return foo;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        //Arrange
        IFoo testFoo = getMockFoo();
        BarInfoObj testInputBar = new BarInfoObj()
        {
            ServerName = "SuccessAddNewBar",
            BarUrl = "http://some.test.url",
            BarInstanceId = 1,
            Status = BarStatus.Idle,
            StatusMessage = "TestInput",
            StatusReportDateTimeUTC = DateTime.Now
        };

        //Act
        Response<BarInfoObj> testResponse = testFoo.AddBar(testInputBar);

        //Assert
        //Just some arbitrary test; the test isn't important because the exception happens
        //when creating the mock.
        testFoo.ReceivedCalls();
    }
}
```

When I was debugging the unit test code I noticed that the second return value registration for the `AddBar` method throws a NullReferenceException.  I've tried commenting out each one and, when they run on their own, they're fine; no exceptions are thrown.  The exception gets thrown when there are two or more return value registrations for the `AddBar` method.  If I just run the unit test, without debugging, no exceptions get thrown and the test will succeed.  I've done something similar in another set of unit tests which don't throw any exceptions and I can't figure out why this one has a problem.  I've followed the NSubstitute documenation and it appears that this should be doable.  I'm hoping that another pair of eyes might help to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm [struggling to reproduce this](https://gist.github.com/dtchepak/15922554cad92b31d80b53b8e3813856). Can you please provide a test case I can run? Another thing to try is adding [NSubstitute.Analyzers](https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/nsubstitute-analysers/) to your test project, which can help find issues.

Comment: @DavidTchepak Thanks for taking a look at this. The code that I included was a snippet from a small sample project that I created to reproduce the error that I was seeing.  I can upload the source code into a github repo and I'll post the link here.  In the meantime, I'll add the analyzers to the test project, as you suggest, and I'll see what information they provide.

Comment: I updated the question with a link to the github repo that has the source code of the sample test code.  The README.md file has instructions for how to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the repo. I believe this is occurring as the process of stubbing the second call ends up invoking the first stub with a `null` argument (`Arg.Is` returns `null`). NSubstitute realises that this call doesn't match, and so handles the `NullReferenceException`. The test should still work as required -- it just affects debugging when "break on exception" is enabled.

If you update to NSubstitute 4.x this case should be handled without the exception as there is some code to detect that a call is being stubbed and so the first stub will not be checked.

Comment: I verified in my test project that this did solve the problem.  I don't have the time right now to do a major upgrade to NSub 4.x and check any breaking changes so I'm going to assume, for now, that this will resolve the problem in the "real" project.  Thanks for your help and the explanation; I really appreciate it.  I'm so glad I've used NSub.  Not only is it an excellent tool but you and the rest of the maintainers are so helpful.  Thanks for all that you do.